# RAM Dimm heat sink wore off

Tags: memory

My RAM's memory heat sink wears off everytime I open my PC to do some cleaning (I guess turning my case, and laying it laterally makes the heat sink wear off.

Please see the image.
[image]

I need to find a way to reliably put back the heat sink onto the RAM Dimm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use thermal adhesive to do this. Here is one example.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835100013

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things the original thermal solution looks like thermal tape - there's a [review for one varient of the stuff here](http://www.frostytech.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=2276) - thermal tape isn't reusable so you'd need to very carefully peel off the tape you have now before reattachment.

That said, i'd give the ram a shot, sans heatsink to see if there's any issues - if it isn't overclocked, it may work fine as is.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How about removing the tape and using what Uninspired proposed?

Comment: VERY VERY careful peeling. Nail polish remover may help as well. I've not had much experience with thermal adhesive so i have no idea there.